# Android - can't retrieve $metadata from WCF Data Service

Tags: android, wcf-data-services, restlet

I'am using Restlet-Framework 2.1.2, from my Android app, I try retrieve data from WCF Data Service and recieve LogCat error messages:

```
Starting the HTTP client
Get the metadata for http://Server.domain.local:82/northdata.svc/ at http://
Server.domain.local:82/northdata.svc/$metadata
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1154K, 56% free 2966K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+6ms
Can't get the metadata for http://Server.domain.local:82/northdata.svc/
java.io.IOException: Unable to create customized SAX source
...
```

My steps:
I allow INTERNET permission in Manifest file:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

I replace HTTP client:

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpClientHelper(null));
```

and use StrictMode:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I use AsyncTask, my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        {

        try {

            NorthdataService service = new NorthdataService();
            Query<Customers> queryCustomers = service
                    .createCustomersQuery("/Customers");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // return e;
        }
        return customers;
    }
```

What could it be? How I check \ get data from $metadata?

P.S. I open my Data Service links in Android internal browser, it opened.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem:
1.I create new Android project
2.Copy files from Restlet-Framework in to libs folder (in my project):

> org.restlet.jar
>   org.restlet.ext.atom.jar
>   org.restlet.ext.html.jar
>   org.restlet.ext.httpclient.jar
>   org.restlet.ext.net.jar
>   org.restlet.ext.odata.jar
>   org.restlet.ext.ssl.jar
>   org.restlet.ext.xml.jar

3.Create new package "northwindmodel"
4.Import auto-generated java classes fom WCF DataService 
5.Add permissions:

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
>   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

6.Incert code in onCreate:

```
 NorthdataService service = new NorthdataService();
    Query<Customers> query = service.createCustomersQuery("/Customers"); 

    Log.d(log_tag, query.toString());

    for (Customers cust : query){
        Log.d(log_tag, "Customer Name - " + cust.getContactName());
    }
```

Before that I did the same thing, but the problem was resolved after recreate project.